# Have you ever changed your job for a slight cut in pay but for a more relaxed/friendlier environment?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this questions fits this community however I am interested in some stories or people whom done this kind of change. By relaxed environment I mean no teams doing overtime, no manager screaming at you, more relaxed co workers who don't give their blood for the company.

Comment: Meta isn't the place to ask off-topic questions. If you want to poll this community your best bet is to do so in [chat].

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I will go there

Answer (score 2):

Asking for stories would be off topic.  Asking how to present it to the potential new employer at the interview would be on topic.

It should be possible for a single comprehensive answer to give someone in that situation enough information to make a decision on how to proceed.

Comment: thank your for the kind response. I was more interested in reasons why other developers have left their jobs.

Comment: @AndreiCACIO: I misunderstood then, I thought you were asking if such a question would be on topic.  A stories / experiences question is off topic both here and on the main site.